# Cosmos C# OS Programming

Tags: c#, cosmos

I am building a base os, with COSMOS (I don't have a mac). So, I have successfully got the os to accept three commands, help, shutdown, restart.

However here is the bit I am stuck on:

```
Console.Writeline("Command>");
Console.Readline();
```

This gets this:

```
Command>
[blank space for Readline command]
```

Here is what I want:

1. The 
   `Console.Readline`
   input to be on the same line as 
   `Console.Writeline`

So This is what I want (user interface):

`Command> [user input here]`

Comment: This question is not really related to cosmos...

Comment: how is this NOT related to COSMOS?

Comment: This works exactly the same in any c# console application.

Comment: i see what you mean...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WriteLine` will write a line, hence you should use `Console.Write(...)` in order to not append a `\n` character.

Comment: That will return this: `Command>
[blank space for Readline command]`

Comment: Isn't that what you are looking for?

Comment: What comments and what Enter?

Comment: it should be `Command>` with `[blank space for Readline command]` this underneath, and i have already tried what you suggested, i've used COSMOS before

Comment: You can add a space to make `Console.Write("Command> ")`. If that is not what you ask, then I fail to understand your English. Please rephrase.

Comment: OK... If `Console.Writeline("");` and `Console.Readline();` produces: `Command>` and a space for the input underneath, how do i move the blank space back up to the `Command>` line?.

Comment: Provide an example with an input of `ls`

Comment: But only show what we would see on the screen. Let the cursor be (`|`) the pipe character...